# Why svg animateTransform only activate on first item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

When the first item was hovered and the others would activate too. But when the second item was hovered and the others won't work. How can I let every item animation trigger one by one?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bubble-wrap {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: relative;" id="clip_svg_wrap">
          <clipPath id="clipPath1" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.8)">
            <path d="M44.7,-77.9C57.7,-70,67.8,-57.5,76.2,-43.7C84.6,-30,91.4,-15,92.7,0.8C94.1,16.5,89.9,33,81.3,46.4C72.7,59.8,59.6,70.2,45.3,77.5C31,84.8,15.5,89.2,-0.1,89.4C-15.7,89.5,-31.4,85.6,-44.7,77.7C-57.9,69.7,-68.8,57.8,-75.6,44.2C-82.4,30.6,-85.3,15.3,-84.7,0.3C-84.1,-14.7,-80.2,-29.3,-72.9,-42.1C-65.6,-55,-55,-65.9,-42.3,-74C-29.6,-82,-14.8,-87.1,0.5,-88.1C15.9,-89,31.8,-85.8,44.7,-77.9Z" transform="scale(2)">
              <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="3 3" to="1 1" begin="clip_svg_wrap.mouseenter" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
              <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="1 1" to="3 3" begin="clip_svg_wrap.mouseleave" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
            </path>
          </clipPath>
          <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639569266292-0c11a1dcb91c?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTgwMTgzMA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" width='100%' height='100%' style="position: relative;"></image>
        </svg>
</div>

<div class="bubble-wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: relative;" id="clip_svg_wrap">
          <clipPath id="clipPath1" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.8)">
            <path d="M44.7,-77.9C57.7,-70,67.8,-57.5,76.2,-43.7C84.6,-30,91.4,-15,92.7,0.8C94.1,16.5,89.9,33,81.3,46.4C72.7,59.8,59.6,70.2,45.3,77.5C31,84.8,15.5,89.2,-0.1,89.4C-15.7,89.5,-31.4,85.6,-44.7,77.7C-57.9,69.7,-68.8,57.8,-75.6,44.2C-82.4,30.6,-85.3,15.3,-84.7,0.3C-84.1,-14.7,-80.2,-29.3,-72.9,-42.1C-65.6,-55,-55,-65.9,-42.3,-74C-29.6,-82,-14.8,-87.1,0.5,-88.1C15.9,-89,31.8,-85.8,44.7,-77.9Z" transform="scale(2)">
              <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="3 3" to="1 1" begin="clip_svg_wrap.mouseenter" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
              <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="1 1" to="3 3" begin="clip_svg_wrap.mouseleave" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
            </path>
          </clipPath>
          <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639972585193-e360d1bd1dd2?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTgwMTgzMA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" width='100%' height='100%' style="position: relative;"></image>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You've two elements with id="clipPath1" that's invalid. All id values must be unique within a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example there is an SVG element for each image. This includes a `<image>` with a unique id and a `<defs>` where the clip-path is defined. The `<clipPath>` also have a unique id. The result is that a unique image is making use of a unique clip-path, and the animation is started and ended with reference to that particular image.

If there are many images that need this clip-path we can agree that this is not an optimal solution. Reusing an already defined clip-path would be better, but as you discovered a "common" clip-path for all images will animate the clip-path on all the images at the same time. I have researched this and also tried a bit of JavaScript and reading the spec for begin-value without any clues on solving this.

Going for a CSS based animation could be a solution, but at the same time it it also limited what you can do in a setup like that.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bubble-wrap {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: relative;">
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath1" transform="translate(100 100)">
      <path d="M44.7,-77.9C57.7,-70,67.8,-57.5,76.2,-43.7C84.6,-30,91.4,-15,92.7,0.8C94.1,16.5,89.9,33,81.3,46.4C72.7,59.8,59.6,70.2,45.3,77.5C31,84.8,15.5,89.2,-0.1,89.4C-15.7,89.5,-31.4,85.6,-44.7,77.7C-57.9,69.7,-68.8,57.8,-75.6,44.2C-82.4,30.6,-85.3,15.3,-84.7,0.3C-84.1,-14.7,-80.2,-29.3,-72.9,-42.1C-65.6,-55,-55,-65.9,-42.3,-74C-29.6,-82,-14.8,-87.1,0.5,-88.1C15.9,-89,31.8,-85.8,44.7,-77.9Z" transform="scale(2)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="2" to=".5" begin="img1.mouseenter" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from=".5" to="2" begin="img1.mouseleave" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
    <image id="img1" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639569266292-0c11a1dcb91c?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTgwMTgzMA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" width='100%' height='100%' style="position: relative;"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="bubble-wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: relative;">
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath2" transform="translate(100 100)">
      <path d="M44.7,-77.9C57.7,-70,67.8,-57.5,76.2,-43.7C84.6,-30,91.4,-15,92.7,0.8C94.1,16.5,89.9,33,81.3,46.4C72.7,59.8,59.6,70.2,45.3,77.5C31,84.8,15.5,89.2,-0.1,89.4C-15.7,89.5,-31.4,85.6,-44.7,77.7C-57.9,69.7,-68.8,57.8,-75.6,44.2C-82.4,30.6,-85.3,15.3,-84.7,0.3C-84.1,-14.7,-80.2,-29.3,-72.9,-42.1C-65.6,-55,-55,-65.9,-42.3,-74C-29.6,-82,-14.8,-87.1,0.5,-88.1C15.9,-89,31.8,-85.8,44.7,-77.9Z" transform="scale(2)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="2" to=".5" begin="img2.mouseenter" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" from=".5" to="2" begin="img2.mouseleave" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
    <image id="img2" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639972585193-e360d1bd1dd2?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTgwMTgzMA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" clip-path="url(#clipPath2)" width='100%' height='100%' style="position: relative;"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```